# Why everytime I use .load() in AJAX my .ajaxForm() begin to redirect?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a homepage which is `index.html` inside my homepage I have a div which I load all my other page, when I load `addpost.php` inside that div.

I submit it's form using `.ajaxForm()` the page redirects but when I open the `addpost.php` directly in my address bar **it does not redirects** which I want to achieve.

Here is my homepage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sugar and Spice</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="../adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.js"></script>

<script>

CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

$( document ).ready( function() {
  $( '#editor1' ).ckeditor(); // Use CKEDITOR.replace() if element is <textarea>.
  $( '#editable' ).ckeditor(); // Use CKEDITOR.inline().
} );

function setValue() {
  $( '#editor1' ).val( $( 'input#val' ).val() );
}

</script>

<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="other.css"/>
</head>
<body style= "background-image:url('bg.jpg');">
<!-- Navbar
================================================== -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
  <center><img src="banner.jpg"></center>
  <div class="navbar-inner" style= "background-image:url('images.jpg');">
  <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="logo.png" width="20" height="20"></img></a>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
           <li class="">
            <a href="#" class="home">Home</a>
          </li>




        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse side">
                    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                        <li class="">
            <a href="#" class="post">Post</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="#" class="page">Page</a>
          </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>      
            </div>
          <div class="span10 well"> 
            <div class="span10">
      <!--Contect goes here-->

    </div>




</div>

</div>

<!-- Footer
================================================== -->
<footer class="footerwell">
<div class="footercolor">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="pull-right"></a></p>
    <p></p>

  </div>
  </div>
</footer>



<!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-affix.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/application.js"></script>

<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

//$(".span10").load("home.php");

$(".home").click(function(){
  $(".span10").load("addpost.php");

});//close home click

$(".post").click(function(){
  $(".span10").load("post.php");

});//close post click

$(".page").click(function(){
  $(".span10").load("page.php");

});//close post click






}); //close ready

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

And here is my addpost.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Adapter &mdash; CKEditor Sample</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.js"></script>



<script>

    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( '#editor1' ).ckeditor(); // Use CKEDITOR.replace() if element is <textarea>.
        $( '#editable' ).ckeditor(); // Use CKEDITOR.inline().
    } );

    function setValue() {
        $( '#editor1' ).val( $( 'input#val' ).val() );
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="f1" action="some.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="articletitle" id="articletitle" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Featured Image:</td>
        <td><input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152" type="hidden">
        <input name="image" id="image" type="file" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="save" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#save").click(function(){
        $("#f1").ajaxForm();

    });

});






</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the javascript.  Your most likely not preventing the default event.

Comment: We are not mind readers, post your code or we can't help.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I've edited my question.

Comment: You shouldn't try to load `<head>` and `<body>` into a DIV. And you're reloading lots of scripts when you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `.ajaxForm()` correctly. You're not supposed to call it in your click handler, you call it when initializing your form, and it establishes its own submit handler that submits the form using AJAX.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#f1").ajaxForm();
});
```

Since it uses AJAX, the page isn't supposed to be redirected. If you want to redirect to the `action` attribute of the form, use normal form submission, not `.ajaxForm()`.